# What is the "Alternative Operator" to "Replace Multiple OR statement" in $Filter query of "Microsoft Graph API"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to find detail of more than 20 users in one query, so I am trying to use below query, But maximum 15 "or" is allowed in one query. So please let me know operator which I can use instead od using "multiple OR statement"

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(userPrincipalName, 'user1') or startsWith(userPrincipalName, 'user2').......

Answer (score 0):

That's a per request threshold and I don't think it can be directly tackled with a drop-in replacement but here's some other ideas for you to consider:

1) If your application stores the user ids you can use the get directory objects by id endpoint which gets up to 1000 users back in one request https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

2) Keep your current query but use MS Graph $batch requests to send multiple of these queries in one call to MS Graph.  This will require you to construct the JSON batch payload and parse the response. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching